# How do I initialize a class member `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr` object in the constructor initializer list?

Tags: c++, initialization, containers, unique-ptr

My code is as seen below.

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdint.h>

class APodClass
{
    public:
        int x, y, z;
};

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(uintmax_t Width, uintmax_t Height)
            :   WIDTH   (Width),
                HEIGTH  (Height),
                Field   (WIDTH * HEIGTH, nullptr)
        {
        }

    private:
        const uintmax_t WIDTH;
        const uintmax_t HEIGTH;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<APodClass>> Field;
};

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])
{
    MyClass MyObject(1000, 500);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following error.

```
Error C2280
'std::unique_ptr<APodClass,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
...\visual studio\vc\include\xmemory0   655
```

What am I doing wrong here. How do I fix this code?

Answer (score 2):

std::unique_ptr is not copyable so any constructor or algorithm (such as `std::generate`) that copies the elements is not going to work:

```
class MyClass
{
    static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<APodClass>> generate(size_t sz)
    {
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<APodClass>> result;
        result.reserve(sz);
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < sz ; ++i)
            result.emplace_back(nullptr);

        return result;
    }

public:
    MyClass(uintmax_t Width, uintmax_t Height)
    :   WIDTH   (Width),
    HEIGTH  (Height),
    Field   (generate(WIDTH * HEIGTH))
    {
    }
...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the constructor [`vector(size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(), const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) that you're using makes copies of the `val` argument.

As you know, `unique_ptr` is not copyable. Therefore you may not use the constructor that copies the argument.

What you can do, is initialize the vector as empty. The default initialization is sufficient, so there is no need to use the member initialization list at all. To add `n` non-copyable elements into an empty vector, you can use a loop and `push_back` inside the constructor body of `MyClass`.